# Force iframe to Load Full Frame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frame

I have an HTML page (say welcome.html) which contains an iframe to a page I have no control over (say app.html).  The user performs some actions using the app within the iframe and clicks submit.  Once they do this, they are taken to a new page (say thanks.jsp), which loads within the iframe.  Is there a way in which I can force thanks.jsp to load in the full frame and not the iframe once submit is clicked?  Remember, I have no control over the logic behind that Submit button or app.html.  I do however have control over welcome.html and thanks.jsp.  If possible, I would like to stick with HTML and/or JavaScript.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use a framebuster, with a base target in case it fails.

First:

**If** `thanks.jsp` is requested via a post request - redirect so it you present the page as the response to a get request.

Then:

Include framebuster JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (self != top) { top.location.replace(location); }
</script>
```

Finally:

In case the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled, make sure they don't stay in the frame any longer then they have to:

```
<base target="_top">
```

Answer (score 2):

On `thanks.jsp` you can put in the following JS:

```
// Parent window not the same as this one
if (self !=top) 
{
    top.location.href = self.location.href;
}
```

This will work provided that you have `thanks.jsp` on the same server as the original page containing the frame, due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

The above code checks the url of the page you're on, then the one of the page it's executing on (`thanks.jsp`) - if they don't match you're sent to the `thanks.jsp` url. This method works fine when `thanks.jsp` is a static page, but won't carry postdata etc across with it.