# Can I disable JavaScript on pages displaying my page when it is included in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

The page I made is shown on an someone else's server in what seems to be a 100% wide `iframe` with JavaScript ads over it. Can I disable the ads changing the code of my page?

Comment: You might want a [framebuster](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=framebuster) instead?

Comment: you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194346/force-iframe-to-load-full-frame ?

Comment: Vice-versa would work if you display *remote* page in *your* site's iframe - you can restrict what iframe can do via `sandbox` attribute. But you cannot affect remote parent page running your page in an iframe

Comment: You could prevent you page to be iframed with [X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Answer (score 1):

No. `JavaScript` is running client-side (*in the browser*), so you have no possibilities to disallow that.

---

**But what you can do is:** you can prevent being iframed by this ad site and all other sites with some tricks, also in `JavaScript`. See here:
[Prevent iframe stealing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522097/prevent-iframe-stealing)